# Fatal error c1083 permission denied

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Visual Studio 2008.

I downloaded a sample project and unzipped it.

I have to convert it from VS 7 to VS 9. However, the conversion was successful.

However, when I try and compile I get the following error:

```
c1xx : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'C:\NMS\inc': Permission denied
```

However, the inc directory I have used before for other projects. And have successfully included the inc files.

So I am not sure why this project does not work.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's trying to open a *file* called `C:\NMS\inc`, which it can't if that path is a directory.

Comment: Any idea why it would be trying to open a file?

Answer (score 1):

This error comes when you have defined a variable in "Additional Include Directories" column and that variable has no value.

check the same by following the path:
Right click on the solution->Properties->C++->General

Two ways to Solve:
Suppose the variable defined is **AX**

1. create a batch file

   - set AX="path of your include directory".

or

2. Right click on my computer->properties->Advanced System Settings->Advance(Tab)->"Environment Variables"->system variable and add or define that variable with its value(which is the path of your directory).

**Note in both the cases the value can be the path of your include directory
or If you don't wish to give path in that variable give it a fake path(like "c:\")**

Define your path again in the project properties.
and restart the VS.
it will work..

Comment: A similar error will occur if a variable is undefined in "Additional Library Directories". A warning message will also explicitly state that the variables have no value if this is the case. This was tested on VS2008.